# Is there a way to check all questions/answers posted from a deleted account

Tags: discussion, support, deleted-questions, deleted-accounts, deleted-answers

Suppose I know an account number, say user313948.

Is there any way to check all questions/answers posted by that user?

Comment: The query mentioned in the answer is given also in this answer on Meta Stack Exchange: [Why not keep anonymous profiles accessible?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/270541#270544) (Although the topic of that question is not exactly the same.)

Comment: Here is a similar post on [math.meta.se]: [Is it possible to know the questions and answers by a no longer user?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/30273).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, with this [Data Explorer Query](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/405958/get-posts-list-of-a-deleted-user?UserId=9072) (enter the Id without "user" part). As I did not find any posts by user313948 specifically, I used another deleted user for illustration purpose.

EDIT: Here are also separate queries showing [questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/942474/questions-of-a-deleted-user?userid=9072) and [answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/942475/answers-of-a-deleted-user?userid=9072) by a deleted users with some additional details (score, viewcount, ...) It is possible to make queries searching for [questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/942476/questions-of-a-deleted-user-with-a-given-tag?userid=9072&tagname=nt.number-theory) and [answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1191925/answer-of-a-deleted-user-in-a-given-tag?userid=9072&tagname=&tagname=nt.number-theory) only in a specific tag. You can also find all [comments by a deleted user](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1189200/comments-by-a-deleted-user?userid=9072).

Comment: It was just for an example. I randomly said that number..

Comment: I could not find anything.. Can you check user312648

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik There are no results for that user number.

Comment: @S.Carnahan That was user no in MSE. I am just checking if there are any posts in MO. user number will be same for both right?

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik No.  MathOverflow is still far from creating user number 200000.

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik If you want a specific example where you also find some posts, you can try [userid 9072](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/405958/get-posts-list-of-a-deleted-user?UserId=9072). This user (and also the relevant SEDE query) was mentioned in another discussion: [What happened to the dear user “quid” (9072), they appear deleted?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2827) (But it is useful that now we have a separate question about this.)

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik If you meant user312648 *on Mathematics* (rather than MathOverflow) then [there are 151 posts](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/405958/get-posts-list-of-a-deleted-user?UserId=312648).

Comment: I apologize for not reading the previous comments carefully enough. Only know I noticed that that user4412195 chose the same example as I suggested in the comment. And in my previous comment I missed that Praphulla Koushik knows userid on Mathematics but is looking for posts on MathOverflow. I hope my answer at least help a bit with MathOverflow posts of the same user.

Comment: @S.Carnahan Oh. Thanks for the information.

Comment: @MartinSleziak That was useful :)

Answer (score 2):

From [this comment](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3748/is-there-a-way-to-check-all-questions-answers-posted-from-a-deleted-account#comment16388_3749) is seems that you were interested also in some additional information:

> That was user no in MSE. I am just checking if there are any posts in MO. user number will be same for both right?

Although it is digression from the original question (which is already perfectly answered), I might at least add something to this - which might clarify some confusion.

---

The user id of the same user on different sites is different. You can check for yourself that your user id is [118688 on MathOverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/users/118688/praphulla-koushik) and [537667 on Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/537667/praphulla-koushik).

I am not aware of a simple way to find other deleted profiles in case I know one of them. (See also this post on Meta Stack Exchange: [Will my deleted accounts be linked?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/251354)) In this specific case I was able to find [Mathematics profile](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://math.stackexchange.com/users/537668/cello) and [MathOverflow profile](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:https://mathoverflow.net/users/100241/) of this user in Google Cache. (In both cases, the cached version is from 15 March 2018. If I understand correctly how Google Cache works, the content you can see there now is likely to be removed at some point in the future - to be more precise replaced with the new version which essentially contains only the information that the account does not exists.)

So we see that userid on MathOverflow was 100241. The SEDE query returns [no posts](http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/405958/get-posts-list-of-a-deleted-user?UserId=100241). (The same query returns [151 posts for the Mathematics user](https://data.stackexchange.com/math/query/405958/get-posts-list-of-a-deleted-user?UserId=312648).) In the Google Cache of the MathOverflow profile I see three posts displayed among "Top Posts": [Prerequisites for reading characteristic classes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/291473), [How does one introduce characteristic classes](https://mathoverflow.net/q/292871) and [References on principal G bundle and connections](https://mathoverflow.net/q/286323). Since all of them are now associated with your account, I assume that the old account (with the id 100241) was at some point merged with your current account. (Maybe the moderators can confirm whether this is indeed the case. Or maybe you can tell whether this is the case - if you requested the merging yourself.)

Comment: Thanks. I am not interested in merging for now :D