# Keyword Search of the User's own (my own) questions or answers

Tags: support, user-interface, user-accounts, searching, profile-page

> Is there a (good) way to "search" the keyword of the User's own (my own) previously asked questions or given answers in one's own profile?
>
> If so, how? Please illuminate.

p.s. I asked that because I wanted to locate some contents I may have asked before. So I need to do Keyword Search for my own profile/questions/answers.

Thank you!

Comment: You could try typing *keyword wonderich site:mathoverflow.net* into Google.

Comment: To me, the tag ([meta-tag:support]) seems more suitable for this question than ([meta-tag:discussion]).

Answer (score 7):

You can find various search modifiers [in the help center](https://mathoverflow.net/help/searching). Or simply by clicking on "Advanced Search Tips" after you [search for something](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=).

Specifically, to find posts by a specific user you can user `user:userid`. And to find your own posts you can use `user:mine` or `user:me`.

Notice that if you go to some user's [profile page](https://mathoverflow.net/users/current), the search query `user:userid` is already pre-filled in the search bar.

For example, you can search for [user:27004](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3A27004) or [user:me](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3Ame). (The first one searches among the posts of that particular user - I chose the OP of this meta question as an example. The latter automatically populates the search box with your own user id and searches for your own posts.)

Of course, you can combine this with other keywords, tags, search modifiers (such as `is:a` for answers, `is:q` for questions), etc. For example, [user:me is:a [ct.category-theory]](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aa+%5Bct.category-theory%5D) returns your own answers in the tag [ct.category-theory](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/tagged/ct.category-theory). Similarly, [user:me is:q url:"*arxiv.org*"](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aq+url%3A%22*arxiv.org*%22) returns my questions containing a link to arXiv. Or [user:me quantum](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3Ame+quantum) searches for the word "quantum" in your own post.

---

See also:

- Several posts on Meta Stack Exchange: [Search/browse my own questions easily](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13424), [Searching/Filtering my own answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305702), [Make it possible to search for questions and answer for a particular user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/12795), [How do you search for questions filtered by a particular user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/15484), [Searching for a particular user's questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38778).
- Several posts on Math Meta Stack Exchange: [How to look up users' specific answers?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/11320), [How to intersect users and tags?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4051) (t.b.'s answer contains a screenshot - although the interface changed a bit since then), [How do I search my own answers.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21959)
- Some basic information on searching is linked in the [corresponding tag-info](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/searching/info).
- Not about exactly the same question, but still related: [What is my user ID?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98771) (Meta Stack Exchange), [Help with what is my user id and how do I check it?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6598) (Mathematics Meta) and [Is there a way to check all questions/answers posted from a deleted account](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3748) (Meta MathOverflow).

Comment: When I use `user:me` I get a different result from `user:27004`, Your answer is therefore wrong, misleading, and very unhelpful!!! :-P

Comment: @AsafKaragila I have added a clarification. Of course, if you still consider the answer unhelpful, that's what downvotes are for.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how I do it.

I click on my own little user icon at the top of the page

[image: icon]

and this puts my own userid into the search field

[image: search]

where I can then add keywords I want to search for.