# Feature request: displaying all answers of a given user

Tags: feature-request, answers, searching

It frequently happens that I want to find my old answer. The list of answers on my page consists of 35 pages, so searching in it using my browser search is too time consuming. On the other hand, if I enter the search terms in the "questions search" it does not show me those questions where the
terms occur in answers. I understand that expanding capabilities of search can be difficult, though very desirable. But it seems that adding a feature which displays all answers of a given user in one page (instead of in 35 pages) must be easy.

Comment: Perhaps try in the MO search field e.g. `user:25510 "bezout theorem"`, which should result in https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3A25510+%22bezout+theorem%22, with two hits from 2014.

Comment: @jeq: your tip is truly amazing. On the top of my screen (of my user page) I see a black stip in which it is written "Search Math overflow". When I enter user25510 "bezout theorem", it gives nothing. It never gives anything at all, whatever I enter after user 25510. However if I enter the address https://mathoverflow.net/search to my browser, then I really obtain the search screen which works. Thanks for showing me this secret link.

Comment: I always enter MO through this page https://mathoverflow.net/ or through this page https://mathoverflow.net/users/25510/alexandre-eremenko. Where on any of them is a link to https://mathoverflow.net/search?? All I see is a black strip in the top which looks like search. But when I enter user:25510 "bezout theorem", it DOES NOT find anything.

Comment: @jeq I will add that you can also add "is:a" to only list answers. And when somebody searches for his own posts, they can use "user:me" instead of number: https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3Ame+%22bezout+theorem%22+is%3Aa

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I did exactly what you describe. (I.e., entered the string into the "black strip".) I got the search results as expected: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l4hu.png I got exactly the same thing as if I go directly to: https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3A25510+%22bezout+theorem%22

Comment: If you want a more compact view listing all answers, you can also use [SEDE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info). (Although the data in SEDE are only updated once a week.) List of [all answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1234440/all-answers-by-a-specific-user?userid=25510) and [all answers including tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1239813/all-answers-by-a-specific-user-including-tags?userid=25510).

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko Now I noticed that you wrote `user25510` in your fisrt comment. You should use `user:25510` instead (with colon). In fact, if you go [to your profile](https://mathoverflow.net/users/25510/alexandre-eremenko), this is already prepared there. See also: [How to intersect users and tags?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4051) and [How do I search my own answers.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/21959) on [math.meta.se]. (The first link has also a screenshot, also it is done in the old interface.)

Comment: Since searching was discussed a bit, I will also add a link to this FAQ post on [math.meta.se]: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265#29266)

Comment: Thanks to all who answered. This was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly about the feature you asked for, but let me leave here a brief comment. (Hopefully, some of the information here might be useful.)

One possibility to get list of all your answers (or questions) in a more compact form then here on the site is to use [SEDE](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/data-explorer/info). (With the caveat that the data in SEDE are only updated once a week, so you won't find the most recent posts there.)

Basic knowledge of SQL helps when using SEDE - but many various queries already exist, so often you can find some queries and simply change the parameters.

For example, query [listing all answers by a specific user](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1234440/all-answers-by-a-specific-user?userid=25510). Similar query which also [shows tags](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1239813/all-answers-by-a-specific-user-including-tags?userid=25510) or [body](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1234439/all-answers-by-a-specific-user-including-body?userid=25510) of the answer.

[image: Screenshot]

You can also check [all questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1234402/all-questions-by-a-specific-user?userid=25510), and perhaps [include the body](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1234404/all-questions-by-a-specific-user-including-body?userid=25510).

---

Let us compare what some search result look like if you use SEDE and if you user built-in search engine.

You can limit the search to a specific user by using [user:25510](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3A25510) or simply [user:me](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3Ame) if you're looking for your posts. (If you go to [your profile page](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/users/current) or to the profile of some other user, the modifier `user:userid` is already prefilled in the search box.) You can restrict the search to answers/questions using [is:a](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=is:a) or [is:q](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=is:q).
To get corresponding results in SEDE you need to specify this in the query. (For example, in the table Posts we have `PostTypeId=1` for questions and `PostTypeId=2` for answers.)

You can find answers by a specific users in some given tag: [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1239827/answers-by-a-specific-user-in-a-given-tag?userid=25510&tagname=ag.algebraic-geometry), [search](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3A25510+%5Bag.algebraic-geometry%5D+is%3Aa).
You can search for some specific phrase in answers: [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1239822/answers-by-the-given-user-with-the-given-phrase-case-insensitive-accent-insensi?userid=25510&word=bezout%20theorem), [search](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3A25510+%22bezout+theorem%22+is%3Aa).

Similarly, you can look for questions in a specific tag: [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1235404/questions-by-a-specific-user-in-the-given-tag?userid=25510&tagname=ag.algebraic-geometry), [search](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3A25510+%5Bag.algebraic-geometry%5D+is%3Aq).
Or for questions with some specific phrase: [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1239857/questions-by-the-given-user-with-the-given-phrase-case-insensitive-accent-insen?userid=25510&word=curve), [search](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=user%3A25510+is%3Aq+curve).

I will add that the SEDE queries linked above only search in the *body*. The table Posts contains also the field Title, which can be used if you want to search for posts using the title. Here are queries searching for [questions](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1239858/questions-by-the-given-user-with-the-given-phrase-in-the-title-case-accent-inse?userid=25510&word=curve) and [answers](https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1239859/answers-by-the-given-user-with-the-given-phrase-in-the-title-case-accent-insens?userid=25510&word=curve) of a specific user based on a word/phrase contained in the title.

---

Further pointers with some information on searching:

- [Help center](https://mathoverflow.net/help/searching); you can find some information also by clicking on "Advanced Search Tips" after you [search for something](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=).
- [Keyword Search of the User's own (my own) questions or answers](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/4221) on MathOverflow Meta
- [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265#29266) on Mathematics Meta