# To moderators: is my account deleted?

Tags: discussion, user-accounts, deleted-accounts

To moderators: Is my account deleted? The rep number is now 1 . but I can still login. I cannot ask this on meta because $1<5$. Thanks for the comments. The account is scheduled for deletion now.

Comment: Did you ask for it to be deleted?

Comment: I did ask 4 times. Got no replies.

Comment: The account asking this question seems to have 45k reputation.

Comment: @NoahSchweber It still reads as 11 in the little box on my screen, though clicking on the link gives 45006. Caching? Bugs?

Comment: It increased from 1 to 45k in the last minute. Now how do I delete the thing?

Comment: @RobertFurber Bizarre! I've opened opened this page in two different browsers in private windows, and am still seeing 45k. I suspect it's caching on your end.

Comment: Why would you want to delete this nice account? Anyway, if you are sure, you should be able to do so at https://mathoverflow.net/users/delete/6976

Comment: @NoahSchweber Only OP gets no 404. You can do the same by replacing 6976 with your account number (8133) and then you can open it while logged in but you get a 404 when not logged in (try it if you want)

Comment: @MarkSapir Sad to see you go. I don't remember -- will we still be able to see your posts?

Comment: @TimCampion Yes. What would appear in place of the name is a number, but all the posts/content would still be there (and also when someone pings him with @ Mark Sapir in comments, that name never goes away). By the way: I don't know what's going on either -- I'm going to try to find out. All I know is that MS contacted us about deleting his account, and he was given a link with instructions about how to do that. (We're not going to push that button ourselves -- such a drastic action for such an esteemed user needs to be completely voluntary on his/her part.)

Comment: @MarkSapir It's a real, real pity that you intend to leave the site ... -- your leaving would be a big loss for the community! -- Even if you choose not to contribute for a while (or even at all any more) -- why do you wish to take such drastic action as to irreversably delete your account?

Comment: @TimCampion In case it is useful: [Is there a way to check all questions/answers posted from a deleted account](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3748).

Comment: I see a mention of a suspension. I have no idea what has happened, but if your decision to delete your account is a reaction to a momentary grievance, let me make a plea for you to reconsider it.

Comment: @MarkSapir: I was also going to suggest what Emil said, though I was going to say 30 days of reconsideration. // In addition, if you're the kind of person that once that has taken a decision, there's _nothing_ that can change your mind, then wouldn't you like to 'donate' your 45k points, by giving bounties?

Comment: How can you ask questions and make comments from a deleted account? Isn't this contradiction?

Comment: @joro It's not been deleted yet.

Comment: @MarkSapir: haha:) noo, seriously you should 'donate' your rep, imagine all the +100 bounties that you might give. You could start a bounty on unanswered and very difficult questions or in questions with answer(s) and reward the outstanding answers, or simply on questions/answer that you like the most

Comment: @Magic_Isa: The best answer to my question on MO was given by Bill Thurston. But I am afraid he is not interested in MO reps now. As I said it is not a practical idea.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is obsolete now.

Answer (score 10):

The drop down to 1 reputation was due to the fact that you were suspended, independent of any discussion of deletion (suspended accounts automatically go down to 1 reputation; I think this was an old hack to remove their privileges).

Since StackExchange has implemented the ability for users to delete their own accounts, we've preferred to go that route over doing deletions by hand, since there should be no question that it was the user's decision.  If you have triggered deletion of your account within the last 24 hours, then you are in the 24 hour waiting period described here ([How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)), and in somewhat less than 24 hours the deletion of your account will be final.

Comment: I agree with the substance. There are cases where deletions may be done by hand for users who contribute poorly.

Comment: How can it be that Mark Sapir has been suspended? -- If this has really happened (I hope not), then let me say that suspending such an eminent contributor is likely to harm the community more than any plausible rule violations from his side may do ... .

Comment: @StefanKohl The suspension period is over. I don't really care to get into a long discussion about the specifics here, but is it your position that sufficient "eminence" (or reputation) means that the norms no longer apply? I suspect there is history here that you are not aware of.

Comment: @ToddTrimble It is quite possible that there is a history which I am not aware of, and in fact I hope it is really drastic -- since if it is not, my feeling is that the decision to suspend him was rather not a good service to the community ... .

Comment: @StefanKohl A suspension, in this case a brief one, is normally a quiet affair, meant to help adjust behavior. A private moderator message is sent out, and there may be a brief exchange. Under normal circumstances the recipient will take the message under consideration, and then will return to activity without fanfare. What's happened is that Mark reacted in a certain way which some might call drastic, and went public about it to boot. I can understand why Mark's announcement upsets people. But it needn't have played out this way.

Comment: Mark, I don't know what you're talking about. I didn't say you were suspended only once. Second, your assertion that you stopped using MO two months ago is blatantly false, as can be easily proven (we know you've been self-vandalizing recently). As for the third, the announcement I was referring to was your public declaration of wanting to delete your account. But I think we're really done being publicly insulted by you (sometimes in deleted comments which could easily be undeleted).

Answer (score 6):

There are alternatives to deletion. In particular, I still have accounts on other stacks that I don't use anymore, but can return to if needed.  You might consider editing your profile to indicate you are taking a MathOverflow sabbatical.

I wish you well on your journey.  Hopefully our paths will cross again,with amicable results.

Gerhard "Say Hi To Ralph Sometime" Paseman, 2020.04.27.

Comment: If somebody decides to keep the account but ignore it (like you suggest), it is useful to switch of the emails that remind you of new responses to your posts/comments. [meta.se]: [Control the types of email you receive via our new Email Settings feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298906)

Comment: Ralph McKenzie has retired last year.