# Procedure for requesting a complete removal from MathOverflow

Tags: discussion, feature-request

With any online community, as the users and the company owning the domain change, it is inevitable that some users will want to exit the community. For example, many Facebook users deleted their profiles after the 2020 presidential election in the USA, and this also deleted their data from Facebook’s servers. However, on MathOverflow, deleting your profile leaves most of your data on the site. Your name will be removed and your profile renamed to something like user12345, but your questions, answers, and comments remain. Also, comments of others like "As David White wrote above, ..." remain unchanged, so it’s easy to realize that user12345 was David White, and to also [gather all contributions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30273/is-it-possible-to-know-the-questions-and-answers-by-a-no-longer-user) [by that user](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/3749/11540).

It is easy to imagine hypothetical scenarios (hopefully all extremely unlikely) that would cause a user to no longer want to be publicly affiliated with MathOverflow, e.g.,

1. The company decides to monetize it, so all users have to pay to use the site (this happened with CouchSurfing, for example).
2. Something terrible happens with the company, so that you as a professional mathematician no longer want to be associated with them (something like this happened with DataCamp).
3. The nature of the community changes radically, e.g., MathOverflow becomes Chegg and everyone comes here to get their homework answered, and again you don’t want to be associated because you don’t agree with the shift.
4. The community changes and becomes known as a nasty place, perhaps one that contributes to the problem of the underrepresentation of women and minorities in mathematics.
5. The political landscape in your country changes, and now you're worried about government prosecution for an opinion you once shared on the site.
6. etc.

I know it’s not popular to think about these kinds of worst-case scenarios, but I do think it’s valuable, especially because the help documents essentially say "any data you put here belongs to you but is licensed to the SE company forever" and tells you that deleting your profile doesn’t remove your data. While we all hope the community agreements and standards hold forever, and make the scenarios above impossible, it’s a sad fact of life that throughout history companies have broken promises to users, or changed in fundamental ways, which would necessitate this kind of exit.

Even if you think none of those scenarios is likely, it’s worth thinking about what will happen to the data you’ve entered on the site, after you die.

If user X wanted to scrub their presence from the site, before deleting their profile, that user could delete every question, answer, and comment they’ve ever posted. Of course, high rep users could still see the deleted questions and answers, but user X could also edit the text down to just a single character, to make it harder to uncover what was there. However, [this kind of thing was once called "self vandalism" by a MathOverflow moderator](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4526/to-moderators-is-my-account-deleted), making me wonder about the question of who really owns contributions. Furthermore, this procedure would take a long time, and it strikes me that moderators have the power to fully delete content (I think it's called "destroying an account"), e.g. as happens with spam answers. Hence my questions:

> (1) How could one automate a complete or maximally-possible removal of one’s data from MathOverflow?

> (2) Is there interest in the community in having the ability to ask moderators to destroy our accounts, for the reasons explained above.

Please don't answer along the lines "According to the terms of service of the site, the following will happen when a user deletes their account..." or "Hey, every user agreed to the terms of service, so it's wrong that they would want to remove their contributions years later." It's worth pointing out that the procedures around deletion and contributions [have changed](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/2844/11540) since many users started using the site, and several of the hypothetical scenarios above are changes that a user might not have been able to forecast when they started using the site 10+ years ago. Rather than answers like "this cannot be done; we own all user contributions forever" I am interested in actual solutions, or in understanding if there is interest in the community in having the ability to request that moderators destroy an account at the request of the user, which would have the effect of deleting all contributions. I would also like to say that I myself am not currently considering deleting anything from mathoverflow, but events over the past year (e.g., the moderator strike, parent company changing policies without input from users, etc.) led me to wonder about how long-time users can exit the community, based on hypothetical scenarios.

Comment: Is it true that in the European Union there is a "right to be forgotten" procedure to follow to get references to you removed from social media?  (As a non-European, I only vaguely remember this, and do not know the details.)

Comment: Somewhat related post on [meta.se]: [How do I remove my name from a post, in accordance with CC BY-SA?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96732) (Of course, removing the user's name is different from deleting the content.)

Comment: Since you "wonder about the question of who really owns contributions", I'll point out this [meta-tag:faq] post on this meta: [Who owns my MathOverflow posts?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/950)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Yes, I'm aware of that and even referenced it. But the idea that someone could commit "self vandalism" of their own posts seemed odd to me. You can see the relevant discussion in the meta thread I linked. The "someone" was Mark Sapir and the moderator was Todd. I have no idea what Mark did. I have been wondering if a user deleting all their questions and answers would be stopped by the moderators, and if so how that plays into the ownership question.

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked that. (Unless I missed something, you haven't  included those links in your post. ) Unrelated to this, I will add that this part seems a bit imprecise: "that user could delete every question, answer, and comment they’ve ever posted". The software does not allow self-deleting questions and answers in many cases. (Questions: If there is an upvoted answer or at least two answers. Answer: If the answer is accepted. I hope I remember this correctly.)

Comment: @MartinSleziak Actually, I wasn't aware of that, and it's very helpful to know. So, users are not allowed to delete their own contributions, which does raise issues in my mind of ownership. What if a user had an accepted answer but realized later it was badly wrong and/or embarrassing? I guess the only solution then would be to edit it. It feels like if the user owns it, then they should be allowed to have it removed upon request.

Comment: @MartinSleziak The Mark Sapir and "self vandalism" thing is here: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/4526/to-moderators-is-my-account-deleted?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Since you mentioned my name, let me point out that "self-vandalism" isn't my concept. It's considered a violation across the SE network, and SE policy has always been to revert such actions. "Please do not vandalize your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted."

Comment: By the way: although site mods can destroy accounts, such actions do not destroy content.

Comment: @ToddTrimble Probably it is worth mentioning that the posts with *negative* score are deleted in such case. And that the mods have an option to delete an account together with all posts - but the later option is probably used rarely and reserved mainly for spammers. At least if the information here is not outdated: [Does deleting an account delete the associated posts and comments?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78629) It seems that this is actually called *destroying* a user: [What is the difference between a deleted user and a "destroyed" user?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88994)

Comment: Suppose someone went to a university library and grabbed a hard copy of a journal with a paper they wrote in it, and because of the publisher being bought out by a dodgy outfit they didn't like, ripped their paper out of the journal so they were not longer associated with the publication — it would be called vandalism. If one instead paid a hacker to delete one's article from off the publisher's website and entire database as well, that would be vandalism. Our answers here are donated to the community, and aren't wholly our own. Doesn't answer your question, but puts context around "vandalism"

Comment: A scenario which might be even worse than the ones you mention, would be one where for some moral reasons the future dominant community of MO would impose changes on old posts. E.g., "It was proved by Euler" would be considered in 2040 as offending and replaced with "It was proved by Her Majesty Euler" and corrected accordingly on then-old posts. (This one is deliberately ridiculous, but I have more polemical and plausible similar ones in mind, which I'll refrain from mentioning.)

Comment: @YCor - the version history is (at least at present) baked into the system, so all such changes are attributed (and this is needed for the Creative Commons license, I suspect)—if only to a system bot/'Community user'. In principle, if one has a personal website hosted by an external company, it might decide to have a backdoor installed and then edit posts to suit certain views. Or Google could systematically edit YouTube videos to contain certain things and not others. But this is getting ... quite intricate.

Comment: I don't want to get off-topic on vandalism (might be good for a separate question). What throws me is that "vandalism" is not defined. The idea is that an edit should make the post better, and I don't know what happens if there's disagreement on that subjective judgment. Or, if the OP thinks the answer must be deleted because it has an error and is embarrassing, but a moderator thinks it's still useful. Labeling the author as a "vandal" could be seen as a way to silence them and remove their agency; potentially a power move by moderators. No offense intended; just thinking about optics.

Comment: @DavidRoberts I'm not sure the average user thinks of content on MO as analogous to journal publications. The platform emphasizes speed. I can't tell you how many times I've found stuff I wrote as an early grad student and cringed (because of writing quality, or naivety). Perhaps it's natural as one gets older to think about legacy, and curating one's body of work. With my hypothetical scenarios in mind, and the clear fact that SE would never relinquish control of my content, I think I might tell my younger self not to join MO, given the chance.

Comment: I googled the keywords from Todd's comment, and stumbled upon an exact instance of the kind of thing I was afraid of. Someone asked a question about dealing with an unethical chair. Then StrongBad answered. Then the OP tried to delete the question and, failing that, to edit out the text she'd written, saying that she was afraid of reprisals. But StrongBad was a moderator and refused to delete it, since "it already has an answer" (namely: his). This was not "self vandalism" - it was an OP being prevented from deleting despite safety concerns https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/78742/66685

Comment: Since the question linked in the previous comment by @DavidWhite is deleted at the moment, here is a Wayback Machine snapshot: [Unethical requests from the senior professors and chair](https://web.archive.org/web/20210928054008/https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/78739/unethical-requests-from-the-senior-professors-and-chair).

Comment: The idea that a user could decide to remove all their posts and the site has to comply is thoroughly incompatible with the letter and spirit of the CC-BY-SA licence. If you want to retain full control of the fate of content you create, there is no solution other than not publishing it under a licence that warrants free distribution of the content.

Comment: @DavidWhite I used non diamond powers to repair vandalism and then used diamond powers to temporarily lock the post while the content dispute was resolved. I suggested two courses of action that I thought were suitable since the post did not contain any identifying information and was from a throw away account. OP never followed up explaining why those suggestions where insufficient or asking for a different moderator to step in. Had they, a different conclusion could have been reached.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes, I think you're right. I suppose that, if any of the hypothetical scenarios came to pass (it sounds like the first would be a flagrant violation of CC), the solution would be for a user exiting the community to write up a reason why, and link to it from their profile here. Like "This site used to be X, then became Y, and I stopped contributing." However, things like scenario 5 do concern me. Imagine if we'd had an Afghani contributor, then the Taliban took over, and view this as aiding the West's scientific/military complex.

Comment: Perhaps the downvotes here are for committing "thought crime." No one has really addressed the actual question (of how to remove contributions, or having the ability to ask moderators to "destroy" your profile), but I guess at least the comments here will serve to show future readers that SE will cling to anything you post to MO, regardless of your wishes, changes to the site, bad behavior by SE, etc. In light of that, I think people should be very careful what they post (or, not post at all), treating it more like a journal, as David Roberts suggested.

Comment: I interpret the downvotes instead to reflect the view that some people don't think it should be possible for a user to delete content in the way you are seeking.

Comment: @DavidWhite You have remarked several times about possible bad behavior by SE, and so I wonder whether you are aware of the special legal nature of MO with respect to SE, explained here: https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/970/1946. The long and short is that we as a community can decide to bring the entire MO site outside of SE if we should wish, and this might address some of your concerns.

Comment: @DavidWhite Instead of "mass deletion," maybe the title should say "complete" or "total" deletion? When I first saw the word "mass," I thought it meant the deletion of the content of a huge number of users all at once. But I think you're referring to deleting the content of a *single* user, with the emphasis being on complete extirpation of all records, rather than the volume of deletions?

Comment: *"Even if you think none of those scenarios is likely, it’s worth thinking about what will happen to the data you’ve entered on the site, after you die."* And why on Earth would I care about *that*??? I have injected certain amount of good and evil into this world, and when I leave, it will be entirely its problem how to digest it or how to spit out. Mostly it is its problem even when I'm still alive.

Comment: In most (if not all) scenarios that you suggested, wouldn't disassociation of the user account from the post (rather than deletion) be satisfactory? (At the same time, I will admit that I do not remember disassociation being used on such a large scale - only for individual post.) One should add, that even in the case when somebody deleted all of their posts, if the content was saved somewhere before that, it would still be possible to find the original username from the saved copy.

Comment: @MartinSleziak I think David White's concern is that sometimes the identity of someone can be inferred even if the name is deleted. He mentions this at the end of his first paragraph.

Comment: People who have the same concerns as the OP would probably be in favor of posting anonymously on the site. Here are some previous discussion related to this: [On the role of anonymity in a site dedicated to research-level mathematics](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/1113) and [Anonymity Policy](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/2574). (And some discussions on the old [tea](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/tags/tea/info) are linked there.)

Answer (score 7):

This is a community-wiki summary of some of the comments.

First, a few preliminary clarifications. The [MathOverflow corporation is completely independent from Stack Exchange](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/970) so we should not to conflate the two. Users [own their content](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/a/951), but by posting, they release their content under the terms of the CC BY-SA 4.0 license. This means that the MathOverflow corporation is under no obligation to comply with a request from a user to eradicate all traces of the content formerly provided by the user. To introduce such an obligation would require a major change in the license agreement, which is not a realistic possibility.

Moderators can [destroy a user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/88994), which means that the user's content will be deleted; however, deletion is not the same as complete extirpation, since deleted posts remain visible to users with sufficiently high reputation. Therefore, even if the moderators agreed to institute a policy (or even an automatic process) to honor requests for destruction, David White's "worst-case scenarios" involving severe human rights abuses would still not be addressed.

An imperfect but possibly useful analogy is an open-source mathematical journal. Most people would regard attempts to destroy journal articles as an act of vandalism, even if someone was destroying their own articles. Stack Exchange similarly has a concept of [self-vandalism](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/209436).

Comment: Good point about the title. I've updated it, to try to make it clearer what the question is about. Also, it's worth pointing out that, because of the periodic data dumps, even if a user is "destroyed" there is an easily accessible record of their past contributions, which is worth bearing in mind for anyone concerned about the "worst case scenario" https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/315378/does-archival-interfere-with-attribution-removal